# QueryDSL predicate for the equivalent query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I want to create an equivalent **predicate** for the query below,

> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE t_date < NOW() ORDER BY updated_at DESC
>   LIMIT 0,10

Right now I am up to this, in the `start` and `end` I will pass the `LIMIT` values such as **0,10**

```
   simpleRepository.findAll(SimplePredicates.pastRecords(), new PageRequest(start, end,
   QuerydslHelper.sortDescBy(QMyEntity.myEntity.updatedAt)));
```

And in the predicate,

```
    public static Predicate pastRecords() {
     QMyEntity myEntity=QMyEntity.myEntity;
     return myEntity.tdate.before(new Date());
     }
```

I am getting the result as desired, but I am not sure if this is the right way.

Any other possible solutions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The predicate in Querydsl is the 'where' part of the JPQL query. Your pastRecords() implementation looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  is it ok to use `.before(new Date())` for `<NOW()` or do you prefer any other alternatives?